# Create a material-UI form stepper

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I am trying to embed a form inside a material-ui stepper. I am wondering if their is any easy way to do this, as instead of showing the Text field it is printing out the HTML.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Button, Paper, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MobileStepper from '@material-ui/core/MobileStepper';
import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight';

import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin:'0 auto',
    width: '90%',
  },
  paper:{
    padding:'5vh',
  },
  button: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  instructions: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

function getSteps() {
  return ['Set Up', 'Budget and Target', 'Creative', 'Review'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return '<TextField id="Name your ad" label="Standard" />';
    case 1:
      return 'Budget and Target?';
    case 2:
      return 'Creative!';
    case 3:
        return 'Review'
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

export default function BuildAdStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
  const steps = getSteps();

  const isStepOptional = (step) => {
    //return step === 1;
  };

  const isStepSkipped = (step) => {
    return skipped.has(step);
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    let newSkipped = skipped;
    if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
      newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(newSkipped);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleSkip = () => {
    if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
      // You probably want to guard against something like this,
      // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
      throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped((prevSkipped) => {
      const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.add(activeStep);
      return newSkipped;
    });
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>


                <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
                    {steps.map((label, index) => {
                    const stepProps = {};
                    const labelProps = {};
                    if (isStepOptional(index)) {
                        labelProps.optional = <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>;
                    }
                    if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
                        stepProps.completed = false;
                    }
                    return (
                        <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
                        <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
                        </Step>
                    );
                    })}
                </Stepper>
                <div>
                    {activeStep === steps.length ? (
                    <div>
                        <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                        All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
                        </Typography>
                        <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
                        Reset
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    ) : (
                    <div>
                        <div>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</div>

                            <MobileStepper
                                variant="progress"
                                steps={4}
                                position="static"
                                activeStep={activeStep}
                                className={classes.root}
                                nextButton={
                                    <Button size="small" onClick={handleNext} disabled={activeStep === 5}>
                                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                                    {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
                                    </Button>
                                }
                                backButton={
                                    <Button size="small" onClick={handleBack} disabled={activeStep === 0}>
                                    {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
                                    Back
                                    </Button>
                                }
                                />

                        </div>
                    
                    )}
                </div>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
</Grid>



    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's occurring because you're returning a string `'<Textfield ... />'`. You need to return an element, not a string.

Comment: By easier way, what do you have in mind? Say like you write all the form fields, and just switch what's shown along eash step?

Comment: He means that in your getStepContent you have a string `'<TextField id="Name your ad" label="Standard" />'` remove the apostrophes to make it a React.ReactNode `<TextField id="Name your ad" label="Standard" />`.